# Running IronPDF on AWS Lambda - Can't Unpack Binaries to /tmp (.NET/C#)

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda

I'm trying to run a simple proof of concept running IronPDF on an AWS lambda. The code deploys fine, but upon invocation IronPDF can't unpack the binaries needed for Chromium to render my PDF.

[IronPDF Installation Docs](https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/installation/#installation-paths)

I am using serverless + csharp template and the function invoked fine before adding IronPDF.

I've tried to manually set the installation directory, but I get a permssion error:

"IronPdf.Installation.TempFolderPath currently set to '/tmp' but has insufficient user permissions for deployment.\nPlease check that this directory exists and full permissions are granted for the current application user"

As far as I know, AWS lambda user has full permissions to "/tmp", but I've never ran a .NET lambda before.

EDIT: I was able to write a text file to /tmp without issue.

```cs
       public Response Hello(Request request)
       {
         IronPdf.Installation.TempFolderPath = @"/tmp";

         IronPdf.HtmlToPdf Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
         var PDF = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<h1>Hello from DocThread</h1>");
         PDF.SaveAs("/tmp/sample.pdf");

         return new Response("Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!", request);
       }
```

Lastly, I imagine that this is just an issue of me being new to C#/.NET on AWS Lambda. It's a fairly common pattern to write files to /tmp before uploading to S3.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was fighting this issue also, and I just figured it out.  Here is what I did:

- Run IronPDF locally and set the TempFolderPath to a directory that you can find quickly.  IronPdf will unpack the necessary files (two .dll, a .dylib, and a .so) to this directory.
- Find the unpacked files in the TempFolderPath set above and copy IronPdf_ChromeRenderingEngine.so to the root of the Lambda project.
- In Visual Studio, set the **Build Action** to **Content** in the properties tab for the .so
- In Visual Studio, set the **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy if newer** in the properties tab for the .so
- Add `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ":" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"));` to the constructor for the Lambda.
- Set `IronPdf.Installation.TempFolderPath = @"/tmp";`

I also set my MemorySize to 512 and Timeout to 180 in the serverless.template, because I was maxing out on Memory at 256.

I hope this makes sense and helps you solve your issue!

Comment: Was finally able to get around to testing your solution. Worked perfectly! Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Are you currently using IronPdf successfully on AWS Lambda? Current version is throwing an exception of "Your platform x64 Amazon.2 is currently not supported by IronPdf".